# Ruby on Rails: Adding another Or Clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am supporting a legacy application with Ruby on Rails (Rails version 4.2).

I have a search functionality, where I have on the user interface one search box.

There is a functionality that already exist.

The user can enter a search term and submit the search, and in the back end the code will search for this "search term" in 7 columns, and all of them belong in one table (the table **"Tickets**" with the model **Ticket**)

The 7 column names are stored in an array Ticket::SEARCH_FIELDS
and the search will be all SQL "like".

So the sql statement WHERE clause will be

```
Select .... FROM Tickets WHERE (column1 like '%term%' or column2 like '%term%' or ....)
```

so the code that build this where clause is as follows

```
query = Ticket.where(
   Ticket::SEARCH_FIELDS.map { |field| 
          ticket.arel_table[field].matches("%#{search_term}%") 
               }.inject(:or)
        )
```

The code is working fine.

But there is a new requirement to add one more column to those 7 columns, but that column is not from the same table but from a lookup table called Employee.

There is already an association between the two model in the Model definition for Ticket,  as follows:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
         belongs_to :employee
```

So, I want to add to the previous where clause another OR clause with that column as follows:

```
WHERE column1 like '%term%' .... OR employees.name like '%term%'
```

I tried few attempts but without any success.

I really appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is a very special case, and very few people will encounter it. But I found a way around this:

```
table_columns = Ticket::SEARCH_FIELDS.map { |field| 
      ticket.arel_table[field].matches("%#{search_term}%") 
employee_column = Employee.areal_table[:name].matches("%#{search_term}%")
table_columns.append(employee_column)
query = Ticket.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN employees on tickets.employee_id = employees.id").where (table_columns.inject(:or))
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in Rails 6. Should work in version 4.2 as well.

```
query1 = Ticket.joins(:employee).where(
   Ticket::SEARCH_FIELDS.map { |field| 
          ticket.arel_table[field].matches("%#{search_term}%") 
               }.inject(:or)
        )

query2 = Ticket.joins(:employee).where(Employee.arel_table[name].matches("%#{search_term}%"))

query1.or(query2)
```

---

edit:

While Rails 4.2 doesn't support `or`, you can use a backport library such as https://github.com/Eric-Guo/where-or to get the same functionality.

Comment: The "or" between the two queries is not working on 4.2. 
Getting the error:

NoMethodError - undefined method `or' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>

Comment: Added a library that can be used to backport the `or` functionality to Rails 4.2